# Zero knowledge proof applied to a chess position

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, zero-knowledge

I know next to nothing about cryptography. From what I have understood, anything that is provable can be done so using a zero knowledge proof (the result seems to be known from the 1980's or so, by S. Micali & al.)

Starting from a given chess position, I want to use zero knowledge proof for a Prover to convince a Verifier that the position contains at least a checkmate in one move. It is assumed that the Verifier doesn't calculate this from the known position.

Chess positions can be simplified to [FEN chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation#:%7E:text=Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards%20Notation%20(FEN),Scottish%20newspaper%20journalist%20David%20Forsyth.). Here is a chess position `6Q1/8/8/8/8/8/5K2/7k w - - 0 1` that contains 4 ways to checkmate Black's king within 1 move, so it satisfies the criterion.

From what I understand, I should now transform the problem into a 3 colors map problem. If I can do so and reduce the problem to "if this map can be colored with 3 colors such that no colors are adjacent, then there is at least one checkmate in the given FEN". From there, I understand that the zero knowledge proof would be completed, as the Verifier could ask the Prover to reveal adjacent colors over and over (and the Prover would reset the choice of the coloring between each time).

How can I do this? How can I transform the FEN chess notation into a map, or a graph that would satisfy the conversion problem?

Comment: please define/explain what a FEN is.

Comment: @kodlu a FEN is a string of characters that encode a chess position. By looking at the FEN you can place all the pieces on a board, know which player it is to move and know castling rights and en passant rights, too.

Comment: well, this is a description, not a definition. it belongs in the question. and an explicit definition of what it represents should be provided since the question is about converting that expression to a graph.

Comment: @kodlu I'm not sure why there is so much focus on the FEN. I mentioned it, but it isn't even necessary. It's just one way, of many, to encode a chess position. It's not part of the main question which is simply "how do I prove this chess position contains at least one checkmate, without revealing anything about the move?".
There are more efficient ways to encode a chess position (bitboards) and less efficients (PGN), than FEN. I put a FEN here just as an example.

Comment: I don't know anything about chess, so I'll just leave a comment here. The 3-colorability proof system isn't probably what you want to use in a practical implementation. Instead, you can think of the game as a program storing a sequence of states encoded in FEN (whatever this is) and each move to the program creates a new state assuming it is legal. Therefore, what you want to prove here is that give some state, you know a move for the appropriate player that will lead to a state that counts a check make (whatever this means).

Comment: So just to clarify again, you can think of this as a program or circuit that takes as input, a state, a move, the new state and outputs whether the move is legal and the state is check mate. Once you describe that program, you can implement it using for example the [Halo2 proof system](https://zcash.github.io/halo2/index.html)

Comment: @MarcIlunga Yes, that's it. A checkmate is a position where a king is threatened, and there is no legal move left.

However your second comment is very vague. First, there's no doc about Halo2 on Github. Second, chess engines have routines that check legal moves and check for checkmates already. I do not wish to implement this at all. How is this related in any way to 0k proofs?
Let's say, as  in the example in my question, that I want to do it for a single position. What's the general idea?

Comment: I don't see any sense in your question. *"Starting from a given chess position"* - Since the position is known, then automatically it is known if there is a checkmate in one move.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik, I agree the Halo2 documentation can be improved, but "there's not doc" is a bit of a stretch :). The link I posted describes the proof system in the “concepts” section.  Maybe also take a look at [this example](https://scroll.io/blog/proof-generation#working-example-square-fibonacci) on the modified Fibonacci sequence. In this case  they prove knowledge of the $k$'th sequence value.

Comment: Regarding chess engine, this is exactly how you go about this. You'll represent the checks of the check engine as a set of “constraints”. Now, imagine you have a table field with values of the initial set, the move and the final set. Your constraints will be equivalent to what a chess engine does (if done) correctly. Using, Halo 2 (I don't mean implement), you can prove knowledge of the move satisfying the requirements of the question. You are free to convert this into a 3-coloring problem, of course ; )

Comment: @mentallurg I interpret "that the position contains at least a checkmate in one move" as there's still one move to be done. Also, consider scenarios where the positions aren't actually known but we only have a commitment to them.

Comment: @MarcIlunga: This single move is obvious. If there are several single moves, they all are obvious, too. The OP is similar to following question: "Prove the knowledge of number between 7 and 11 that is dividable by 3".

Comment: @MarcIlunga: *"Also, consider scenarios where the positions aren't actually known"* - This has nothing to do with the OP. The OP says clearly *"Starting from a given chess position"*, which means that the position is known to everyone in advance. This is exactly the reason why I see no any sense in the OP.

Comment: @mentallurg, the obviousness of the computation doesn't matter when the question is about feasibility. Zk is about not learning more than being convinced. Also regarding known positions, I didn't mean that was the question :) Again in ZK it is often the case that known to everyone in advanced means literally known to anyone. Again, my reading of the question is about feasibility.

Comment: @MarcIlunga sorry, the first time I checked the website you linked, the doc on Github was down. There was literally no doc about halo2. But now I can see it (without the error 404 from Github). :)

Comment: @metallurg You are wrong. Yes, the chess position is known to everyone. Even to someone who doesn't know Jack about chess. He may be wondering whether there is a checkmate in 1, whatever this means to him. In this case, if he can get the zero k proof that indeed there's a checkmate, then bingo. The question does make sense, even though you are unable to see it.

Comment: And here's an implementation of what I am looking for: https://github.com/risc0/risc0/tree/main/examples/chess. "This code demonstrates a minimal example of how to use the RISC Zero zkVM to make ZK proofs about chess.

The demo uses the shakmaty crate to prove that a chess position has a checkmate without revealing what that checkmate is."

Damn, seems like my question made sense after all? :)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but in the example you gave, I couldn't understand what is the purpose of proving whether a chess state has at least one checkmate in a single move. As a prover, what I have to prove to verifier is not whether the state contains mate in a move or not, but that I know that move. So what needs to be proven as an argument here is "there is checkmate in one move and I know it."

Comment: On the other hand, I think the concept of ZKP can be relaxed in this problem. It is not computationally difficult for the verifier to find all possible checkmate moves for that state. If the purpose of the prover is hiding move from the other party, I think  [Witness Indistinguishable Protocol](https://www.isical.ac.in/~rcbose/internship/lectures2016/rt02feigeshamir.pdf) provides sufficient conditions for this purpose.

Comment: @NB_1907: *"As a prover, what I have to prove to verifier is not whether the state contains mate in a move or not, but that I know that move."* - Exactly. That's why the OP in its current form makes no sense.

Comment: Compare it to factorization problem. The fact that you can prove that the given number is not prime and can be factorized does not mean that you know how to factorize this number.

Comment: The linked GitHub repo contains the same logically *wrong* statements as the OP. It states: *"prove that a chess position has a checkmate"* - It makes no any sense. It would make sense if the text was "prove that the prover knows how to checkmate". But in its current form it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: *"may be wondering whether there is a checkmate in 1, whatever this means to him"* - This statement makes no any sense. For proof, both parties need to have *the same* definition of what checkmate is. If they have different definitions of checkmate, then obviously neither can the prover prove nor can verifier verify anything.

Comment: The linked GitHub repo **has nothing to do with cryptography**. It is just a set of applications. They abuse the words *zero knowledge proof*. What they do is following: They involve a 3rd party that actually gets knowledge and that tells to the verifier the result. It is **snake oil**. I suggest to **close the question**.

Comment: @NB_1907 and mentallurg, the verifier needs not how to play chess. Just like in the common example of a colorblind person who seeks to know whether someone else knows which of 2 balls is green, which is red. What is obvious to you is not obvious in an absolute sense. Also, remember that anything provable admits a 0K proof. And my statement is something provable. Closing the question without giving an answer is a coward way to escape it. But I'll post it elsewhere, for I am convinced it makes sense.

Comment: Does "a given chess position" imply that this position is known to the verifier, and includes everything beyond the position of pieces to determine legal moves (rook, en- passant)?

Comment: @fgrieu yes. That's what FEN provides. All the information needed to make the next move. Castling rights and en passant are taken into account. You can.do the same with bitboards too.

Comment: In one comment you say: *"to someone who doesn't know Jack about chess. He may be wondering whether there is a checkmate in 1, whatever this means to him."* - This means a person that have no idea of chess. In another comment you say: *"the verifier needs not how to play chess"*. These two statements contradict each other.

Comment: @mentallurg I do not see any contradiction. The verifier doesn't need to know how to play chess to be convinced that.there is a checkmate. My 2 statements are in agreement with this. A similar aegument can be said about the colorblind man who cannot tell the colors of his balls by using his eyes. He can.still verify their colors via 0k proof.

Comment: You have provided a lot of possibly useful information regarding the question in the comments. Please edit your question and incorporate them. Comments can be deleted, removed.

Comment: Thank you @kodlu. I will do this. I am not sure exactly what is worth adding.

Comment: @kodlu I have just re-read my question, and someone has apparently modified it by adding clarifications. Do I need to put more stuff? To me, it is extremely clear as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for Prover to prove to Verifier a property (exists chessmate in 1 move) about a chess position<sup>#</sup> they *BOTH* know. This is not what a Zero Knowledge Proof is designed to solve.

A standard kind of Zero Knowledge Proof aims at proving to Verifier that a property applies (or not) to the position known by Prover, without revealing anything else about that position to Verifier (here: without the Verifier gettign any clue about the position, beyond that it belongs to the set of positions with chessmate in 1 move). That is possible at least in principle. Basically we codify the finite set of operations to determine if the proposition stands or not, and give a ZKP proof of that.

If indeed we assume the position is known by Verifier, perhaps we really want that Prover demonstrates that they know a move that chessmates, without revealing anything about that move. I think that's possible in principle too: Prover gives a zero-knowledge commitment to the move, and a zero-knowledge proof that the committed value chessmates.

In both cases the details are beyond my current expertise, and I can't tell what size the proof would be, nor how hard it's to compute and verify.

---

Update: My statement above [was misunderstood](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236059). It's that three things *are* possible in zero knowledge:

1. For a position they know, Verifier gets convinced of the value (true or false) of the proposition "exists chessmate in 1 move". No communication with Prover is necessary, all that's needed is Verifier applying a finite set of rules. No crypto is involved. No data in the protocol trivially implies that the protocol is zero knowledge.
2. For a position they do *not* necessarily know, Verifier gets convinced of the value (true or false) of that same proposition. They do not learn anything else about the position. This requires communication with Prover. But that's not what the question is about, thus I did not explore ramifications according to if we assume Prover is honest, or a third party knowing the position verifies that Prover is honest, or Verifier gets convinced that Prover is honest (e.g. because Prover committed the position in zero knowledge).
3. For a position they know, Verifier gets convinced that Prover knows a moves that checksmates. They do not learn anything about which move Prover is thinking about, if there are several.

---

Update 2: We can also read the question as: For a position they know, Verifier gets convinced that Prover ran an agreed-upon algorithm that determined that "exists chessmate in 1 move". This can be seen as a special case of 2, in the ramification where Verifier gets convinced that Prover is honest, but with reduced work and communication because Verifier knows the position. Since the position is known in advance, that knowledge can not leak, thus as far as I can tell any protocol convincing the Verifier is zero-knowledge (and, like in 1, not one making good use of ZKP). The method of 1 (run the algorithm on verifier side) remains better on every count.

---

<sup>#</sup> "position" is in a notation that includes everything needed to decide the valid next moves (including w.r.t. castling and en-passant). Should we generalize to "Chessmate in $n>1$ moves", we may further assume the position was never reached before, and neutralize the 50-moves rule, so that there can't be ambiguity about if a line of play results in a draw.

Comment: Every provable statement that admits a proof, also admits a 0k proof. Therefore, I believe your 1st paragraph is wrong. The rest of your answer is based on a different problem, or case.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik: I'm not stating that for a given position it can't be proven in zero knowledge that exists chessmate in 1 move. On the contrary: the verifier knowing the position can unambiguously find the status of the proposition "exists chessmate in 1 move" by applying a finite set of rules to the position, without any communication with the Prover, thus in zero-knowledge. It's just that the framework of zero-knowledge proof is of no help here, because the verifier knows the position. Perhaps read after "If indeed we assume" / #3 for what you really are asking.

Comment: you are making a fallacy in assuming that the verifier can himself verify if there is a checkmate if he knows the position. He may not know the rules of chess. And even if he knew chess, he could still make a mistake. However he will be convinced by a 0k proof. He won't be shown which move(s) the prover has found.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik: it's indeed possible to assume Verifier does not want to apply the rules of chess themselve, only get convinced that Prover applied them. I (now) discuss that in Update 2. Basically it's a proof that some computation was performed. But I do not see what "zero knowledge" means in that context (zero knowledge <=> Verifier learns nothing beyond the proposition proven). Also Verifier will have much more work (thus opportunity of error) than applying the rules of chess, or will need to trust Prover or a third party.

Comment: The verifier doesn't learn anything about the checkmate move. He can get convinced by asking the prover to reveal adjacent node colors on a graph for example.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik: ah so we are next to my 3, plus Verifier would want to not directly apply the rules of chess like in my Update 2. I'm pretty sure that Verifier will have to trust that some given algorithm implements these rules. And even if I remove the requirement that Prover does not disclose the winning move, anything I can think of requires a lot of data from Prover, and more work for Verifier than running the algorithm to get a full proof. It may however be possible for Verifier to get say 90% confident with less than full work.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik, it is not possible for the verifier to not know the rules of chess. Something in the realm of the verifier has to know the verification algorithm. The only thing that gets closed to this is that the Verifier only has some commitment or encrypted version of the program, and the prover proves the desired property.

Comment: Also, we need to review what ZK means... The formal notion of ZK boilds down to the verifier shouldn't be able to compute more than they could before the ZK protocol. But here is the thing, every NP language has an ZK-proof doesn't mean that for each problem a verifier many never learn information. Some problem may actually be in P, in that case the verifier could already compute the solution. Note that this doesn't contradict the ZK property at all. It's just that the ZK proof in this case is somewhat less interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your input @MarcIlunga,  I have to read them carefully and try to understand them well. Regarding risc0, it seems at first glance a serious 0k proof setup, to me, but I may be wrong.